# Accessing o365 Exchange emails via Java application

Tags: java, server, oauth-2.0, exchange-server, azure-ad-msal

Currently I use JavaMail API to retrieve emails from exchange server inbox using imap.

The exchange server is now migrated to o365 online, and basic authentication is being disabled. So, I need to use OAuth2 and integrate with Microsoft Graph APIs using Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) to retrieve the emails from exchange server.

Has someone achieved this and can provide pointers for this integration? I am specifically looking to read emails from a system inbox/account using OAuth2 and Microsoft Graph APIs.

Thanks,
Saurabh